# Lock.protect and callsame

Tags: thread-safety, raku

I'm trying to write a trait to threadsafe a `sub` automagically.  This is what I've got:

```
#| A trait to ensure that a sub is not run on multiple threads simultaneously.
multi sub trait_mod:<is> (Sub \code, :$protected!) {

    # If :!protected, do nothing.
    if $protected {

        # Create a new lock outside the multithreaded area
        my $lock = Lock.new;

        # Wrap the sub with a routine that hides callsame in a lock
        code.wrap: sub (|) {
            $lock.protect: {callsame}
        }
    }
}

#| Should print "Start X and finish X" if properly protected
sub needs-protection($x) is protected {
   print "Start $x and ";
   sleep 1;
   say "finish $x";
}

# Test it out.
# If not protected, completes in 1 second with malformed output
(1..4).hyper(:1batch, :4degree) { 
   needs-protection $_
}
```

However, AFAICT, it seems that the `callsame` isn't doing anything (it returns `Nil` but that's it).  My guess is that it's somehow attempting to call a different candidate for `.protect`, but I don't see a way to ensure that the `callsame` is linked to the wrapped sub, rather than some other method.

I was able to get it to work by doing

```
multi sub trait_mod:<is> (Sub \code, :$protected!) {
    if $protected {
        my $lock = Lock.new;
        code.wrap: sub (|c) {
            if CALLERS::<$*PROTECTED> {
                $*PROTECTED = False;
                return callsame;
            }

            $lock.protect: { 
                my $*PROTECTED = True;
                code.CALL-ME(|c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that feels cludgy and I'm probably missing something that allows a `True` value for `$*PROTECTED` to slip out when things aren't safe.  Is there a way to make a direct `callsame` while inside of a `protect`-ed block?

Comment: What about something akin to mixing in [a monitor](https://github.com/jnthn/oo-monitors) that provides a `CALL-ME` method?

Comment: raiph: I mean, definitely possible.  This is just something that came up when I was rewriting some code to use hyper — I'm super curious here why *callsame* isn't working. I know lizmat and jnthn have been doing some work on it, but I don't know if this is a known bug, functioning by design, or what.

Comment: I didn't mean to question your question. I just meant something akin to "I wonder if this would work?" and if it would be a simpler and faster implementation for the trait. I'm still wondering that. I mean, "I mean, definitely possible" is definitely possibly your view of its possibility. It's also definitely possibly not. In other words, I wonder what you mean by "I mean, definitely possible". It *seems* definitely possible that you mean it's definitely possible. It also seems definitely possible you just mean it *seems* definitely possible. Or even definitely possibly definitely possibly? 

Comment: raiph: oh absolutely :-)  Although thankfully as it turns out, the solution was crazy simple.  I actually think I can use it for a module or two I wrote back in the day where I did the dynamic variable trick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deferral routines like `callsame` look for the nearest *dynamically scoped* dispatch to resume. A block `{callsame}` passed to the method `protect` will be called by the `protect` method, and the nearest dispatch in dynamic scope will be the method dispatch to `protect`. Therefore, it will attempt to defer to a `protect` method in a base class of `Lock`. There aren't any, thus the `Nil` result.

To solve this, we need to obtain the wrapped target in the correct dynamic scope, and make it available lexically. This can be achieved using `nextcallee`:

```
#| A trait to ensure that a sub is not run on multiple threads simultaneously.
multi sub trait_mod:<is> (Sub \code, :$protected!) {
    # If :!protected, do nothing.
    if $protected {

        # Create a new lock outside the multithreaded area
        my $lock = Lock.new;

        # Wrap the sub with a routine that hides callsame in a lock
        code.wrap: sub (|c) {
            my &target = nextcallee;
            $lock.protect: { target(|c) }
        }
    }
}

#| Should print "Start X and finish X" if properly protected
sub needs-protection($x) is protected {
   print "Start $x and ";
   sleep 1;
   say "finish $x";
}

# Test it out.
# If not protected, completes in 1 second with malformed output
for (1..4).hyper(:1batch, :4degree) { 
   needs-protection $_
}
```

This gives the output that I expect you are expecting.

Comment: Okay, I feel silly now.  I can only think I glossed over *nextcallee* by lumping it with the others like *callsame*, *nextwith* etc that return the result of the call, rather than a reference to the next one — and it's clearly designed for exactly what I was doing.  Thanks jnthn++ !